# Code fails to detect float number as more than 0 in C++

Tags: c++

The instruction given in my assignment is to make a negative decimal tally i.e., adding negative numbers only and ignoring the positive numbers with or without decimals.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float num1, num2, num3, num4, result;

    cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4;

        if (num1 > 0)
        {
            result = num2 + num3 + num4;
            cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << result;
        }
        else if (num2 > 0)
        {
            result = num1 + num3 + num4;
            cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << result;
        }
        else if (num3 > 0)
        {
            result = num1 + num2 + num4;
            cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << result;
        }
        else if (num4 > 0)
        {
            result = num1 + num2 + num3;
            cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << result;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

```
My input: 10 20.5 -2.2 -1.8
Output: 16.50 // The -2.2, -1.8 and 20.5 were added here.
Expected Output: -4.00 // The -2.2 and -1.8 were added.
```

The problem is that it detects 20.5 when it is told not to add any numbers greater than 0.

Comment: you got the logic wrong. You should use a debugger to see what your code does. WHen the first number is greater than zero you add all the other numbers. And "it is told not to add any numbers greater than 0." is not what your code does

Answer (score 1):

You should check not only one number but everyone:

```
std::cin >> n1 >> n2 >> n3 >> n4;
float result = 0;
if (n1 < 0) {
    result += n1;
}
if (n2 < 0) {
    result += n2;
}
if (n3 < 0) {
    result += n3;
}
if (n4 < 0) {
    result += n4;
}
std::cout << result;
```

Comment: This is technically correct, but there's a lot going on here which I imagine the op hasn't covered yet.